# Changing specific lines of code from all my HTML pages

Tags: html, xhtml, xhtml-transitional

Let's assume that

1. I have thousands of HTML files.
2. All of them use's the same CSS layout.
3. All of them are made with exactly 100 lines of code.

Now, I would like to replace lines 40-50 from all of these files with a common set of 10 lines. Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes. This isn't a question about HTML though, it's a question about batch modifying files in general. If you **want** it to be about HTML then I'd ask why you're not using some templating system so that you don't need to change **thousands** of HTML files.

Comment: You should look into PHP and include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a html related topic. You should use a programming language.

- Creat a program.
- Loop through each of your html files.
- Replace the desired lines of code (or any other string) with your new content.

By the way if your purpose is just to manipulate a bunch of classes/IDs and content, it's doable with javascript/jQuery. but unlike first solution it will run each time one of your html files are loaded in a browser. i don't recommend this.